# Why does Jupyter notebook stop executing after a line is re-run after an error?

Tags: tensorflow, compiler-errors, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-console

For the [Encoding categorical data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnxcj.png) data section, the first time I ran it, I got an error because I didn't have sklearn installed. After I installed it and re-run, I got In **[ * ]**. No matter how many times I run it, it's not executing. Basically, after an error is made, all lines can't be executed again.

One thing I found out is that this Jupyter Notebook is under tensorflow environment. This is what I did from the beginning:

1.Create tensorflow environment, then install tensorflow

2.Import the libraries, it didn't work because matplotlib not installed by default

3.Then install matplotlib

From my own troubleshooting, this is where the problem begins. So I tried to uninstall matplotlib, it's fine again [as shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbDdk.png)
Now even there's an error, I can still re-run the line and the execution is fine because the number will be updated instead of [ * ].

Then the problem arises again because if I keep running it, it will turn into [*] again after maybe 3rd or 4th times. The thing is if I do the same thing with Jupyter notebook under root environment(no tensorflow installed, matplotlib is installed), I can keep re-running it for as many times and there's no problem(the number will be changed). So what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem came from tensorflow python 3.6. I tried many different methods to troubleshoot. Lastly I removed tensorflow environment, and reinstalled as python 3.5, Jupyter notebook is working fine now. It won't stop executing. Does 3.6 have to be fixed?